# Android Gridview with a sliderbar not scrollbar

Tags: android, gridview, seekbar

hi guys i need to develop an design with the grid-view and scroll-bar in the right and it comes as default but what i need is to scroll the grid-view only when the user touches the scroll bar then only the grid-view should scroll otherwise it should not...

so i thought of having a vertical seek-bar in the right and side of the grid-view to achieve my goal but need your comments and any other easiest way to achieve the same.

Hope you all could understand my question if not please let me know...

[image]

Edit #1:
hi please see this image... this ui is what i actually want... In this when i scroll in the grid-view area the grid-view will not scroll but when the bar on the right of the grid-view it scrolls...

Edit #2:
Hi guys i have achieved what i actually needed and now i have an additional task. All that i need now is to remove the click event of the seekbar and have only the drag event in the seekbar. Have tried by setting clickable false but no effect...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: hi @IlangoJ i have update my question with the ui design what i need.. I have not implemented any code yet... But i have a simple grid-view right now...

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is the way to go. You can extend the girdview and overide the onTouchEvent to return false. This should prevent the gridview from scrolling.

And there are many tutorials for the vertical seekbar. You can use the scrollTo method of the gridview to programatically scroll the gridview.

Comment: i have implemented the thing what i needed and now i have one more addition to it... i need to have only drag event in seekbar and click event should not happen... I have tried by setting clickable false but still no effect... Hoping for a better response... Thanks...